# Looking for a free Morphing - Ageing program for Mac OS X.6

Tags: mac, software-rec, photos

I'm looking for a free morphing and/or ageing software for Mac OS X.6, not too hard to use, with the kind of Mac "one click" function, if you know what I mean.
Cheap programs are also welcome, I paid for a Photoshop license, so why not another software...
My goal is to be able to modify faces, make them look older or younger, add some piercing or other, funny stuff.

Thanks for your tipps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already paid for Photoshop then your best use of time is to learn how to do age progressions with Photoshop.

Any decent artist will tell you that you can't "one click" half of the stuff they do. It takes a good eye, some practice, and some time. Age progressions are particularly tricky to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After learning better how to use Photoshop, I found all I wanted. My request was for another "Freeware" capable of doing this, and only this, but I'll survive with that option. Thx again.